# RowEditEvent not sending new values primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

When I add a new row to the list it will be added just fine. However trying to edit the row will open it in editmode. But no new values that I have entered will be passed to the backing bean. Crash happens when pressing the edit pen to save.

It will of course crash on a null pointer exception in the receiving function.

I have had it working before. But I can't seem to get it to work in Primefaces 5.1 or 5.2.

```
Aug 24, 2015 12:42:08 PM com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl handlePartialResponseError
SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sg.bowlingInfo.backingHallmastaren.onRowEdit(backingHallmastaren.java:127)
```

---

```
<p:dataTable id="hallmastaren" var="bi" value="#{backingHallmastaren.listHallmastaren}" editable="true">
        <f:facet name="header">
           Hallmästaren
       </f:facet>

        <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{backingHallmastaren.onRowEdit}" update=":form:msgs" />
        <!--  p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{backingHallmastaren.addNew}" update=":form:msgs" / -->

        <p:column headerText="Position">
           <p:cellEditor>
               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{bi.position }" /></f:facet>
               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="positionInput" value="#{bi.position}" style="width:100%"/></f:facet>
           </p:cellEditor>
       </p:column>
<p:column>
           <p:rowEditor />
       </p:column>


    </p:dataTable>
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{backingHallmastaren.addNew}"
                    value="Add" update=":form:hallmastaren" render=":form:hallmastaren" />
```

The receiving function

```
public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
    Hallmaster hm = (Hallmaster) event.getObject();
    double hcp = (220 - hm.getAverage()) * 0.8;
```

Comment: Which is your line number 127?

Comment: double hcp = (220 - hm.getAverage()) * 0.8;

Comment: It mean hm object is `null` or `hm.getAverage()` Please debug and check

Comment: hm is the old value. getAverage is null since the new value was not passed along.

Comment: so now you doing arithmetic operation with NULL value so its sending NPE

Comment: The point is that it's not passing along the information as it should it should not be null.

Comment: Did you edit in the value in datatable for that field??

Comment: In future questions, post a MCVE, not an extracted snippet which doesn't at all demonstrate the problem when placed in a further completely empty template.

Answer (score 0):

For some odd reason moving the form tag corrected the problem.
Original form:

```
<h:form id="form"> <--- Not working
<p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true"/>

    <p style="float:right;">Telefon: 0418-663930</p>
    <p class="Three-Dee">Svalövs Bowlinghall</p>

    <ui:include src="event.xhtml" />

    <ui:include src="menubar.xhtml" />

    <div id="right">

    <p:dataTable id="hallmastaren" var="bi" value="#{backingHallmastaren.listHallmastaren}" editable="true">
        <f:facet name="header">
           Hallmästaren
       </f:facet>
```

Moving the form tag inside the div fixed the problem.

```
<p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true"/>

    <p style="float:right;">Telefon: 0418-663930</p>
    <p class="Three-Dee">Svalövs Bowlinghall</p>

    <ui:include src="event.xhtml" />

    <ui:include src="menubar.xhtml" />

    <div id="right">
    <h:form id="form"> <----- Working
    <p:dataTable id="hallmastaren" var="bi" value="#{backingHallmastaren.listHallmastaren}" editable="true">
        <f:facet name="header">
           Hallmästaren
       </f:facet>
```

Comment: Your problem suggests that there's another form in those include files. Nesting forms is illegal in HTML.

Comment: Only one form so that's not it